# Keyboard layout switches randomly on me, without the system rebooting

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a US keyboard.  My /etc/default/keyboard looks like the following:

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard
# Check /usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian for
# documentation on what to do after having modified this file.

# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="intl"
XKBOPTIONS=""

# If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
# specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
# before /usr is mounted.
# KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Intermittently, the keyboard changes its' layout. I can still type with the alphabet keys but the ' and " keys become special and start putting accent marks above letters. I have found (through searching on askubuntu) a temporary fix by running the following:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

But it doesn't last and is not not correlated as far as I can tell to rebooting -- I leave this machine up all the time as it doubles as my file server. The key board will simply switch on me whether I am using  a terminal, a text editor to Libre Office.  It doesn't appear to matter.

I am perplexed at this one. I just fix it every time and keep the above command handy. But I would love for it to not switch as it is inconvenient. This machine is Ubuntu 20.04 and has been through upgrades all the way back to 14 or earlier -- I forget just how far back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout you have configured is *English (US, intl., with dead keys)*, but it sounds as if you want the basic *English (US)* layout.

Open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file for editing and change the line

```
XKBVARIANT="intl"
```

to

```
XKBVARIANT=""
```

and reboot.